# Timeout error laravel when bulk importing data from api to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2

A laravel application is hosted on aws EC2 instance, i am implementing an api that sends thousands of records and inserted to mysql database.

Upto 1000 records there was no problem, but when i increased the count to 2000+, getting a 504 error or "cant reach this page".

**What i tried**:

1. Increased max_execution_time in apache.conf & php.ini file
2. Increased timeout in apache.conf

but still has no effect, any suggestions

and also in code as well.

```
public function importPostJobsClient(Request $request)
    {
      ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
      ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

      .. other logic code here
    }
```

Comment: Consider offloading your long running process to a [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues).

Comment: Wanted a quick fix something to do execution time.